# Javascript to parse different parts of a specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to convert my Wordpress site to be entirely front-end, REST API driven. I'm getting rid of all of my php and pretty much using Wordpress as a CMS with no php requests. I have a lot of code that Wordpress was parsing for me, but I'll need to handle myself now.

I need to be able to split this into its parts: [my_social artist = "blink-182" facebook = "https://en-gb.facebook.com/blink182/" soundcloud = "https://soundcloud.com/blink-182" spotify = "https://open.spotify.com/artist/6FBDaR13swtiWwGhX1WQsP"]

I'd eventually like the output to be something like:

```
{
    tag: "my_social",
    artist: "blink-182",
    facebook: "https://en-gb.facebook.com/blink182/",
    soundcloud: "https://soundcloud.com/blink-182",
    spotify: "https://open.spotify.com/artist/6FBDaR13swtiWwGhX1WQsP"
}
```

I tried my hands at a regex, but wasn't too sure how to repeat any non-specific key-value groups. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture the content you want:

```
(\w+)\s*=\s*(".*?")|(\w+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/4NmPAJ/1)**

And then you can create a new string using the captured content with:

```
"\1":\2,
```

And also concatenate the string:

```
"tag":"\3"
```

Comment: Nice. I've never seen that .*? syntax before, but that really comes in handy. Thanks!

Comment: @user1771700 that is to transform a greedy operator into a lazy (or ungreedy) operator. It's quit useful to match the minimum match between boundaries

Comment: Yeah it definitely is very useful. I use the .* syntax in most of my operators, but didn't realize you could make it lazy like that. Thanks a lot!